# ¿Cómo relacionar elementos de un Array entre ellos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Dispongo de un código para contabilizar unos elementos recibidos en `json`, para pintarlos en un gráfico, tengo tres tipos de elementos:

> 1. Padre
> 2. Hijo
> 3. Nieto

La lógica que he usado es que a medida que vayan apareciendo se van contabilizando, pero al aparecer un nieto con dos hijos me ha descuadrado completamente.

> - El padre es único, solo sale una vez.
> - Los hijos pueden ser `n`, pero todos apuntan al padre.
> - Los nietos pueden apuntar a varios hijos.

Este ultimo punto es el que me ha descuadrado completamente, ya que si dispongo de:

```
[
    //ELEMENTO PADRE
    {Id: "234L", Padre: "", Nombre: "Padre"},
    //ELEMENTOS HIJOS
    {Id: "247P", Padre: "234L", Nombre: "Hijo1"},
    {Id: "248P", Padre: "234L", Nombre: "Hijo2"},
    //ELEMENTOS NIETOS
    {Id: "50132", Padre: "247P", Nombre: "Nieto1"},
    {Id: "50674", Padre: "247P", Nombre: "Nieto2"},
    {Id: "49964", Padre: "248P", Nombre: "Nieto3"},
    //Elemento nieto con dos hijos
    {Id: "50132", Padre: "248P", Nombre: "Nieto1"}
]
```

Me contabiliza el ultimo hijo mal con la siguiente lógica:

```js
var json = [{Id: "234L", Padre: "", Nombre: "Padre"},
            {Id: "247P", Padre: "234L", Nombre: "Hijo1"},
            {Id: "248P", Padre: "234L", Nombre: "Hijo2"},
            {Id: "50132", Padre: "247P", Nombre: "Nieto1"},
            {Id: "50674", Padre: "247P", Nombre: "Nieto2"},
            {Id: "49964", Padre: "248P", Nombre: "Nieto3"},
            {Id: "50132", Padre: "248P", Nombre: "Nieto1"}];
            
let count = {};

var obj = json.filter(elem => {
  if (count[elem.Id] === undefined) {
    if (elem.Id.includes("P")) {
      count[elem.Id] = 1;
      count[elem.Padre]++;
    } else if (elem.Id.includes("L")) {
      count[elem.Id] = 0;
    } else {
      count[elem.Id] = 1;
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    count[elem.Padre]++;
    count[elem.Id]++;
    return false;
  }
});

obj.forEach(elem => elem.Repetido = count[elem.Id]);

console.log("obj", obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Esto me da de resultado:

```
"obj", [{
  Id: "234L",
  Nombre: "Padre",
  Padre: "",
  Repetido: 2 //BIEN
}, {
  Id: "247P",
  Nombre: "Hijo1",
  Padre: "234L",
  Repetido: 1 //MAL
}, {
  Id: "248P",
  Nombre: "Hijo2",
  Padre: "234L",
  Repetido: 2 //MAL
}, {
  Id: "50132",
  Nombre: "Nieto1",
  Padre: "247P",
  Repetido: 2 //MAL 
}, {
  Id: "50674",
  Nombre: "Nieto2",
  Padre: "247P",
  Repetido: 1 //BIEN
}, {
  Id: "49964",
  Nombre: "Nieto3",
  Padre: "248P",
  Repetido: 1 //BIEN
}]
```

Para que sea correcto `Nieto1` debería contabilizarse en dos sitios el primero en `Hijo1` y el segundo en `Hijo2` ya que está repetido pero cada uno apunta a diferentes padres, así que debería quedar así:

```
"obj", [{
  Id: "234L",
  Nombre: "Padre",
  Padre: "",
  Repetido: 2
}, {
  Id: "247P",
  Nombre: "Hijo1",
  Padre: "234L",
  Repetido: 2
}, {
  Id: "248P",
  Nombre: "Hijo2",
  Padre: "234L",
  Repetido: 2
}, {
  Id: "50132",
  Nombre: "Nieto1",
  Padre: "247P",
  Repetido: 1 //Primer Nieto1 que apunta a Hijo1
}, {
  Id: "50674",
  Nombre: "Nieto2",
  Padre: "247P",
  Repetido: 1
}, {
  Id: "49964",
  Nombre: "Nieto3",
  Padre: "248P",
  Repetido: 1
}, {
  Id: "50132",
  Nombre: "Nieto1",
  Padre: "248P",
  Repetido: 1 //Segundo Nieto1 que apunta a Hijo2
}]
```

**¿Cómo puedo solventarlo?**

Comment: El último elemento está repetido, ¿es intencional?. Por favor aclara a qué te refieres con _Me contabiliza el ultimo hijo mal_, ¿Qué resultado obtienes y cuál debería ser el correcto?

Comment: @Triby Ese es el problema, está repetido pero apunta a otro, edito la pregunta para aclarar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En general, podrías solucionarlo iterando sobre tu array de usuarios y comprobando si cada uno está presente en el  array original.

En este ejemplo se ha usado `Array.map()` para clonar el array original y, para comprobar el numero de repeticiones usamos `Array.filter()` aplicando las relaciones padre-hijo-nieto.

```js
const initialCollection = [
    //ELEMENTO PADRE
    {Id: "234L", Padre: "", Nombre: "Padre"},
    //ELEMENTOS HIJOS
    {Id: "247P", Padre: "234L", Nombre: "Hijo1"},
    {Id: "248P", Padre: "234L", Nombre: "Hijo2"},
    //ELEMENTOS NIETOS
    {Id: "50132", Padre: "247P", Nombre: "Nieto1"},
    {Id: "50674", Padre: "247P", Nombre: "Nieto2"},
    {Id: "49964", Padre: "248P", Nombre: "Nieto3"},
    //Elemento nieto con dos hijos
    {Id: "50132", Padre: "248P", Nombre: "Nieto1"}
];

const withChildren = initialCollection.map(el => {
  const childrenCount = initialCollection.filter(item => item.Padre === el.Id).length;
  
  return {...el, Repeticiones: childrenCount || 1};
});

console.log(withChildren)
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro si es lo que buscas pero podrías probar algo así:

```js
let count = {};

json.forEach(elem => {
  if (elem.Padre !== "") {
    count[elem.Padre] = count[elem.Padre] ? count[elem.Padre] + 1 : 1
    count[elem.Id] = 1
  }
});

const obj = json.map(elem => ({ ...elem, repetido: count[elem.Id] || 0 }))

console.log("obj", obj);
```

El padre quedaría con 0, los hijos con 3 y los nietos con 1.

Comment: Gracias pero no es lo que busco, he editado la pregunta para aclarar el resultado que busco